# Convergence in the Weyl-Kac denominator formula

Tags: kac-moody-algebras

The following is the Weyl-Kac denominator formula:

$\prod_{\alpha \in \Phi^+} (1 - e_{-\alpha})^{m_\alpha}
= \sum_{w \in W} \varepsilon (w) e_{w(\rho) - \rho}$

Now each $e_\lambda : H^* \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$. So I'm assuming the equality is in the ring $\mathfrak{R}$ of integer valued functions on $H^*$.

For Kac-Moody algebras, both the set of positive roots $\Phi^+$ and the Weyl group $W$ are infinite sets. Each individual term of the product on the LHS (and the sum on the RHS) are also elements of $\mathfrak{R}$. So it seems like there is infinite product of ring elements in the LHS (and an infinite sum of ring elements in the RHS). I want to understand how this makes sense. (Especially given that there is no notion of convergence here, since the entire treatment is purely algebraic (right?))

Comment: In Kac's book Infinite dimensional Lie algebras (section 9.7) there is the algebra $\mathcal{E}$ where such infinite sums live, they are of the form $\sum c_\lambda e(\lambda)$ where $c_\lambda = 0$ for $\lambda$ outside the union of a finite number of cones.

Comment: @ArB. Thank you for your answer. This clarifies where the infinite sums and products live. But if I may continue on this, my main motivation for understanding this was to understand how we get Macdonald identities from the denominator formula. Typically what I've seen is that it is simply stated that we can map $e_{-\alpha}$ to $z$ or something similar. So am I to understand this a homomorphism of sorts from $\mathcal{E}$ to $\mathbb{C}$. Because the convergence of these identities in $\mathbb{C}$ is seldom talked about.